# Trouble Scraping with Rvest and Selector Gadget (New Programmer Needs Help)

Tags: html, web-scraping, css-selectors, rvest

I am trying to learn as much as I can using the internet, but am all over the place trying to figure this out.  I am working with rvest and Selector Gadget to scrape data from a table on a website that allows scraping (linecombinations.com).  I have spent days on this and this is where I am now.  Would love some education even more than a specific solution.  Thanks!

```
install.packages("rvest")
install.packages("dplr")
install.packages("stringr")
install.packages("magrittr")

library(rvest)
library(dplR)
library(stringr)
library(magrittr)

url <- "http://www.linecombinations.com/index.php?team=BOS&linetype=evf&range=10"
css <- ".col_66"

webpage <- read_html(url)
print(webpage)
mynode <- html_nodes(webpage,css)

mystr <- toString(mynode)
mystr <- gsub("<!--","",mystr)
mystr <- gsub("-->","",mystr)

newdiv <- read_html(mystr)

newtable <- html_nodes(newdiv,".col_66")
newframe <- html_table(newtable)

print(newframe)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use html_node and add in child `table` [type selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Type_selectors) via [descendant combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator) to css i.e. specify you want child `table` tag element with parent having class `col_66`:

```
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)

table <- read_html('http://www.linecombinations.com/index.php?team=BOS&linetype=evf&range=10') %>%
         html_node('.col_66 table') %>% html_table()
```